# Is there a way to save an entire "alignment field/column" into a NumPy array using Samtools?

Tags: python, numpy, samtools, pysam, bam

In the SAM format, each alignment line represents the linear alignment of a segment, and each line have 11 mandatory fields, i.e. QNAME, FLAG, RNAME, POS, MAPQ, etc.

Let's say I wanted a NumPy array of all "QNAMES" in a given BAM file. Or, one could take several columns and import them into Pandas Dataframe.

Is this functionality possible with pysam?

One can naturally open a given BAM file with `pysam.AlignmentFile()` and then access individual segments with `pysam.AlignmentSegment()`, e.g.

```
seg = AlignmentSegment()
print(seg.qname)
```

However, could you save all QNAMES into NumPy array?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is doable. Note that when importing reads from a BAM file with `pysam` for your purposes, it is best done using the `fetch()` function, which creates an iterator over all the reads (`pysam.AlignmentSegment()` objects) in the BAM file. QNAME is then retrieved using the `query_name` function:

```
import pysam
import numpy as np

my_bam_file = '/path/to/your/bam_file.bam'
imported = pysam.AlignmentFile(my_bam_file, mode = 'rb')
bam_it = imported.fetch(until_eof = True)
# Use head(n) instead of fetch(), if you only want to retrieve the first 'n' reads
qnames = [read.query_name for read in bam_it]
```

Here, `qnames` is a *list* of all QNAMEs in the BAM file. If you *insist* on getting a NumPy array, just add the following line at the end:

```
qnames = np.asarray(qnames)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# pip install pyranges 
# or 
# conda install -c bioconda pyranges

import pyranges
bam_df = pyranges.read_bam(f, sparse=False, as_df=True, mapq=0, required_flag=0, filter_flag=1540)
```